# Android throws NullPointerExpception only if I don't put a breakpoint

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Development. I don't know why it throws a NullPointerException there if I don't put a breakpoint there.

```
Button btnFtpDownload = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.downloadFtpButton);
    if (btnFtpDownload != null){
        btnFtpDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.d(TAG,"Download click");
                Message msg = new Message();
                downloader.start();
                msg.obj = "start";
                downloader.mHandler.sendMessage(msg); //throws a NullPointerException if no breakpoint there
            }
        });
    }
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference
```

**UPDATE**

`downloader` is an instant of a thread class. [Link](https://codeshare.io/eZd3V) to the class in codeshare.io (because it's a very long class so Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to post here)

Comment: post out the code where you have define a downloader.

Comment: Looks like a race condition. `downloader` init probably happens on another thread and does not complete unless you add the breakpoint to pause the current thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does so because 'downloader' does work asynchronously. if you set breakpoint, program freeze main thread, but background thread keep running and when you press next step button, object is ready. But, if program run  without breakpoint (faster), instance is null so exception is thrown.

Comment: What's your suggestion on solving this?

Comment: post more code about 'downloader' maybe there is some 'onReady' callback, in which  you can do that

Comment: 'downloader' is a class , derived from thread, it take some time to start; mHandler is ready only after Looper.prepare() call returned. you can fix it by  posting action on ain thread

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
            }
        }, 100); but this is workaround solution.

Comment: Where do I add those?

Comment: after downloader.start() - then it will be executed with delay 100mSec, it will be enough. But  this is workaround solution. msg.obj = "start";
                downloader.mHandler.sendMessage(msg) in run(){}